# Converting a Multidimensional Array, and/or converting to stdClass Object

Tags: php, matomo

I am having trouble with using the array provided by the Piwik API, in PHP format, as it outputs the code here:

```
array (
 0 => 
  array (
    'idsite' => '2',
    'name' => 'coolrob335.com',
    'main_url' => 'http://coolrob335.com',
    'ts_created' => '2012-06-02 21:05:56',
    'ecommerce' => '0',
    'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
    'currency' => 'GBP',
    'excluded_ips' => '',
    'excluded_parameters' => '',
    'group' => '',
    'feedburnerName' => NULL,
  ),
 1 => 
  array (
    'idsite' => '3',
    'name' => 'robbrazier.com',
    'main_url' => 'http://robbrazier.com',
    'ts_created' => '2012-06-04 14:17:28',
    'ecommerce' => '0',
    'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
    'currency' => 'GBP',
    'excluded_ips' => '',
    'excluded_parameters' => '',
    'group' => '',
    'feedburnerName' => NULL,
  ),
)
```

What I am wondering is this: is there a way to manipulate this array directly, as using $obj[0]['idsite'], $obj[0]->idsite aren't working (I know the latter wouldn't work, as it's not a stdClass object).

So, is there a way to convert the array shown in the link above from

```
array (
   0 => 
    array (
      'idsite' => '2',
```

to something like

```
array (
   0 => 
     array (
      ['idsite'] => '2',
```

or convert it to a stdClass object, so that it can be manipulated? (I have searched SO and google for converting a multidimensional array to a stdClass object, and none of the solutions worked in this case. Possibly due to them not being as `[] => ''`

On a sidenote:
What I am trying to do from this is get 'idsite' and 'name', converting it into a list with 'name' as the title of the link so e.g. it'd be

```
$url = "{$user_data['piwik_server']}/index.php?module=API&method=API.get&idSite={$obj->id}&format=PHP&prettyDisplay=1&serialize=0&token_auth={$user_data['apikey']}"

<a href="<?php $url; ?>"><?php $obj->name; ?></a>
```

(I am aware that this will most likely have to be in a foreach/while loop to work efficiently)

Answer (score 1):

Using the array you provided, the following code:

```
function toObject($any) {
    $rv = new stdClass();

    if (is_array($any)) {
        foreach($any as $k => $v) {
            $rv->$k = is_array($v)
                ? toObject($v)
                : $v;
        }
   } else {
        $rv = (object) $any;
    }

    return $rv;
}

$o = toObject($a);

var_dump($o);
```

will generate this output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["0"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (11) {
    ["idsite"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "coolrob335.com"
    ["main_url"]=>
    string(21) "http://coolrob335.com"
    ["ts_created"]=>
    string(19) "2012-06-02 21:05:56"
    ["ecommerce"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/London"
    ["currency"]=>
    string(3) "GBP"
    ["excluded_ips"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["excluded_parameters"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["group"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["feedburnerName"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (11) {
    ["idsite"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "robbrazier.com"
    ["main_url"]=>
    string(21) "http://robbrazier.com"
    ["ts_created"]=>
    string(19) "2012-06-04 14:17:28"
    ["ecommerce"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/London"
    ["currency"]=>
    string(3) "GBP"
    ["excluded_ips"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["excluded_parameters"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["group"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["feedburnerName"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :)
Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work in this case, it's showing this: http://beta.piwilytics.com/multidimensionalarray.php.
I have a feeling it's because the array is malformed?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some types of variables that you can't cast using `(object)`,  such as resources, or database connection handles

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$arr=array (
    array (
       'idsite' => '2',
       'name' => 'coolrob335.com',
       'main_url' => 'http://coolrob335.com',
       'ts_created' => '2012-06-02 21:05:56',
       'ecommerce' => '0',
       'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
       'currency' => 'GBP',
       'excluded_ips' => '',
       'excluded_parameters' => '',
       'group' => '',
       'feedburnerName' => NULL,
    ),
    array (
        'idsite' => '3',
        'name' => 'robbrazier.com',
        'main_url' => 'http://robbrazier.com',
        'ts_created' => '2012-06-04 14:17:28',
        'ecommerce' => '0',
        'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
        'currency' => 'GBP',
        'excluded_ips' => '',
        'excluded_parameters' => '',
        'group' => '',
        'feedburnerName' => NULL,
    ),
);


foreach($arr as $k=>$v) $obj[$k]=(object)$v;
echo $obj[0]->idsite; // 2
echo $obj[0]->name; // coolrob335.com
```

[**DEMO**.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gius9t)

Comment: awesome! I see how that works with the raw data array, however as I am using the API, and using file_get_contents() on the url, how would I go about this?
what I tried before with what you said showed nothing, however when I put it exactly as you posted, it works perfectly. What i've got at the moment is this:
`$url = "{$server}/index.php?module=API&method=SitesManager.getAllSites&format=PHP&prettyDisplay=1&serialize=0&token_auth={$apikey}"; 
$php = file_get_contents($url);
$arr=array($php);
foreach($arr as $i=>$o) $obj[$i]=(object)$o;
 echo $obj[0]->idsite;
 echo $obj[0]->name;`

Comment: I think it should be `foreach($php as $i=>$o);` if it's($php) the returned array.

Comment: sorry if i'm being a pain, but it's saying `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home2/coolrob1/public_html/piwilytics.com/beta/multidimensionalarray.php on line 28`, which is `foreach($php as $i=>$o) $obj[$i] = (object)$o;` so I am assuming that is an issue with the array $php, however that prints fine normally, I'm a bit stuck. I've laid it out at http://beta.piwilytics.com/multidimensionalarray.php

Comment: You didn't have the array in the `$php` variable.

Comment: Get the `array` first and then supply the array in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: That warning showing that `file_get_contents` can't open that stream.

Comment: so would declaring $php as an array be doing `$php = array(file_get_contents($url));`, so it's an array of `file_get_contents($url)`? however that returns no data. I feel so noobish :(

Comment: I'm not sure about the `url`, I've just answered what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do when using the PIwik API with PHP data, is to set &serialize=1 in the HTTP request (instead of serialize=0 that you are doing), and then simply run

```
$value = unserialize($value);
```

You will then obtain the array ready to be used.